# searchResultsTitle in UISearchDisplayController not working

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nsstring, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I want to customize "No Results" string in `UISearchDisplayController`. In documentation you can find that `UISearchDisplayController` has property `searchResultsTitle` that as I thought should change this string, but it doesn't work.
Please help with customization "No Results" string in iOS 5 and above. And why `searchResultsTitle` doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `searchResultsTitle` property of `UISearchDisplayController` does not actually controls the *No Results* text. If you look at the instance variables of `UISearchDisplayController` you will see both `_resultsTitle` and `_noResultsMessage`. The `_noResultsMessage` is what controls the *No Results* text but has unfortunately no public property.

You can nevertheless set a custom message with this code using the undocumented instance variable:

```
@try
{
    [self.searchDisplayController setValue:@"No Results, try again later." forKey:[@[@"no", @"Results", @"Message"] componentsJoinedByString:@""]];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {}
```

As for `searchResultsTitle`, the documentation is so scarce that I have no idea what it controls!

Comment: do you use above snippet to access private property in your production code? Was it approved within app review process?

Comment: I do not use this specific example in my production code, but I used the same `componentsJoinedByString:@""` technique and it was approved.

Comment: Thanks 0xced for getting back. As per approval - it's both good and bad that Apple (probably) seems to just check binary's linked symbols/libraries.